# Creating a resource group with terraform in azure: Cannot find resource group directly after creating it

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm about to create a small VM with terraform in azure and have come across a curious problem. Terraform creates my resource group but immediately fails when creating the next object (a VNet) that is part of the resource group:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "simple_vm" {
  name     = "simple_vm"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "main"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name = "simple_vm"
}
```

Calling `terraform apply` results in:

```
* azurerm_virtual_network.main: 1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_network.main: Error Creating/Updating Virtual Network "main" (Resource Group "simple_vm"): network.VirtualNetworksClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceGroupNotFound" Message="Resource group 'simple_vm' could not be found."
```

Looking at the web interface shows, the resource group has been created. Calling `terraform apply` a second time correctly finds it and creates the VNet inside the resource group.

To me this looks like terraform tries to create objects in the resource group while it is not yet fully instantiated in azure. I've observed a similar behavior with public IPs: I've created a VM with a public IP and included an `output ...` to print the public ip of the VM. On the first run, the output is empty (no error message though). After `terraform refresh` the output is filled with the IP.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in terraform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay in creation of launch config in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932165/delay-in-creation-of-launch-config-in-aws)

Comment: This is just a generic dependency ordering issue as with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932165/delay-in-creation-of-launch-config-in-aws. Use `depends` on or interpolate the result of the resource group into the virtual network resource so that Terraform knows what order to do things in. We should probably create a generic, canonical question/answer combo for this I guess.

Comment: Here is an interpolation example. As ydestskorR states, this will set up the dependency for you.


resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.name}"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create an implicit dependency like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "main"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.name}"
}
```

In this way, Terraform *knows* that it will need to create the Resource Group first before it can create the vNet.

From Terraform's perspective, your original code simply has 2 independent resources.

Terraform's [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/dependencies) on this is useful. In general, you don't want to set up explicit (`depends_on`) dependencies unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't figure this out myself. Thanks.

Comment: For those of us using terraform 0.12  

  `resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.name`

Comment: what about if we using modules, like the second module fails because resource group name still in process in azure, it takes couple seconds to be available.

Comment: @Harry - better to create a new question with that clearly lays out your problem in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have your "provider" values exported properly before running plan and apply. Sometimes terraform might not know which subscription/resource group it needs to associate and hence, resource not found(404 error) might occur.

Comment: can you explain how to export the provider values?

Comment: This solved my issue.  I forgot to include tennant and subscription in the provider block.  ```provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id = var.tenant_id
  features {}
}```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use the resource group created using the code at the top (azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.name)

I can also see that you are using the same location so you can set in the vnet module the location like follow:
azurerm_resource_group.simple_location

So your code should look like this

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "simple_vm" {
  name     = "simple_vm"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "main"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with terraform 1.1.9 *and* a reference to the resource group (`name = azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.name`).

With terraform 0.13 and up, you can specify explicit dependencies with the `depends_on` input:

```yaml
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "simple_vm" {
  name     = "simple_vm"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "main"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm.name
  depends_on          = [azurerm_resource_group.simple_vm]
}
```

Thanks to the other answers and comments, I realized I forgot to specify the dependencies.