# Terraform tried creating a "implicit dependency" but the next stage of my code still fails to find the Azure resource group just created

Tags: terraform, azure-resource-group

Would be grateful for any assistance, I thought I had nailed this one when I stumbled across the following link ...

[Creating a resource group with terraform in azure: Cannot find resource group directly after creating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933811/creating-a-resource-group-with-terraform-in-azure-cannot-find-resource-group-di)

However, the next stage of my code is still failing...

```
Error: Code="ResourceGroupNotFound" Message="Resource group 'ShowTell' could not be found


# We strongly recommend using the required_providers block to set the
# Azure Provider source and version being used
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.64.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type = string
  default = "ShowTell"
  description = ""
}


# Create your resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = "UK South"
}



# Should be accessible from LukesContainer.uksouth.azurecontainer.io
resource "azurerm_container_group" "LukesContainer" {
  name                = "LukesContainer"
  location            = "UK South"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  ip_address_type     = "public"
  dns_name_label      = "LukesContainer"
  os_type             = "Linux"

  container {
    name   = "hello-world"
    image  = "microsoft/aci-helloworld:latest"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"

    ports {
      port     = "443"
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }

  container {
    name   = "sidecar"
    image  = "microsoft/aci-tutorial-sidecar"
    cpu    = "0.5"
    memory = "1.5"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "testing"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the full error message and where does it exactly occur in the code?

Comment: Try `resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name` also you may be able to add a `depends_on = azurerm_resource_group.example` into the `azurerm_container_group` resource block. If there is a time dependency you may need to provision resources separately or possibly introduce a [time sleep](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep) function.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an implicit dependency you must refer directly to the object that the dependency relates to. In your case, that means deriving the resource group name from the resource group object itself, rather than from the variable you'd used to configure that object:

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "LukesContainer" {
  name                = "LukesContainer"
  location            = "UK South"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  # ...
}
```

With the configuration you included in your question, both the resource group and the container group depend on `var.resource_group_name` but there was no dependency between `azurerm_container_group.LukesContainer` and `azurerm_resource_group.example`, and so Terraform is therefore free to create those two objects in either order.

By deriving the container group's resource group name from the resource group object you tell Terraform that the resource group must be processed first, and then its results used to populate the container group.